# Error when trying to run "npm i -g http-server" on Mac

Tags: npm

I am a total beginner when it comes to programming and have no clue what I am doing. I am doing a course called Your last Intro to Programming Course on Udemy for a local coding bootcamp and I am only in the setup stage and already ran into this issue. I followed every instruction exactly and there is no comments or information on the course to help me figure it out. Please help? (I am on a Mac with the latest software.)

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the permissions on the directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` using `ls -l /usr/local/lib/node_modules` to make sure it is not owned by root. If it is, I would run `sudo chown -R <not root account>`